# Vim Highlight local javascript/node variables

Tags: javascript, vim, syntax-highlighting

So I declare some code like:

```
var http = require('http'),
http.createServer(function(req, res) { ... }
```

Vim will highlight `var`, but how can I make it highlight `http` which is a variable?

Can I use ctags with some plugin to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Vim cannot do that, because it is not an IDE. It does not parse your javascript (or whatever code), which would be needed to do this.

Maybe there is a plugin which does that, but I think that would be really slow.

Comment: TagHighlight does it.. but not for js. at least is does not support corretly node.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are too high.

1. In your example, `http` is not a keyword or any other language element. It's only an arbitrary variable name that could have been `wha7ever` or `someThing_else`. As such, it's not highlighted by Vim in its default configuration.
2. You should look for a node-aware JavaScript syntax file on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/) or maybe modify an existing one by adding a new (possibly very complicated) syntax group.
3. Beware of the "Christmas tree effect": too much syntax highlighting may be worse than not enough.

Comment: well, you can use ctags for c/c++ files then combine it with the https://github.com/abudden/TagHighlight plugin that would do the truc of highlighting vars for you based on the generated tag file. I know there is jsctags of js.. but I wasnt really satisfied with its results :/
I like the christmass tree effect :P very true. (The rainbow plugin is a gd example of hi pushed the the extreme)

Comment: Eclipse can highlight varianle names.